# Make snackbar to appear after arrayadapter click

Tags: java, android-arrayadapter, android-snackbar

I have an `ArrayAdapter` that shows a list of item.

Each item has a button.

When the button is clicked I had like to show `snackbar` (right now it shows a toast message).

I was wondering how I can use something like this inside an `ArrayAdapter`?

```
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),text,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
    sbView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

    TextView tv = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
    Typeface font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getBaseContext(), R.font.assistant);
    tv.setTypeface(font);
    tv.setTextSize( 14 );

    snackbar.setAnchorView(findViewById( R.id.bottom_navigation ));

    snackbar.setDuration( 5000 );
    snackbar.show();
```

Since I don't even have findVireById in an adapter.

The specific part of the adapter is:

```
viewHolder.btn_AddToMyItems.setOnClickListener( v -> {

auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyItemsActivity.class);

Map<String, Object> general_item = new HashMap<>();
general_item .put( "ItemID", item.getId() );
general_item .put("DateCreated", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

CollectionReference colRefMyItems = db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "MyItems" );
Query queryMyItems = colRefMyItems.whereEqualTo("ItemsID", item.getId());
queryMyItems.get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
        if (snapshot.isEmpty()){
            db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "Items" ).add( general_item );
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The item was added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This item is already on your list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        intent.putExtra( "TAG","999");
    }
} );
```

Thank you

Comment: show adapter code

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
    viewHolder.btn_AddToMyItems.setOnClickListener( v -> {

auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyItemsActivity.class);

Map<String, Object> general_item = new HashMap<>();
general_item .put( "ItemID", item.getId() );
general_item .put("DateCreated", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

CollectionReference colRefMyItems = db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "MyItems" );
Query queryMyItems = colRefMyItems.whereEqualTo("ItemsID", item.getId());
queryMyItems.get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
        if (snapshot.isEmpty()){
            db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "Items" ).add( general_item );
           Snackbar.make(v,"The item was added successfully",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else{
Snackbar.make(v,"This item is already on your list",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            
        }
        intent.putExtra( "TAG","999");
    }
} );
```